# Why database that created in phpmyadmin won't show in workbench?

Tags: 16.04, mysql, lamp, phpmyadmin

I just installed LAMP today. I created a database also a tables in phpmyadmin.. But when checking this in MySql Workbench it doesn't show the database? Any one knows came up with these problem?

Comment: Who owns the table in phpmyadmin?

Comment: @George What do you mean who owns it?

Comment: Is the owner `root` or another user you created?

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the mysql databases by running the commandline mysql interface.

Bring up a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Then run this to login as root, which which has permissions to view all the databases.

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

Now after loging in as root, run this:

```
mysql> show databases;
```

After seeing the actually database (as long as it has been properly created, you can use either this interface or the Phpmyadmin interface to give permission to the appropriate database to the userID that will be accessing it.

Some users will not be able to see databases that they don't have sufficient permission to see.

**Granting access to database using the command-line:**

You can do this from the commandline by looking at the database name and running this command from the root access.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON [database].* TO 'userid'@'%';
```

- Replace "[database]" with the name of the database, not including the brackets.
- Replace **userid** with the name of the user you are granting privileges.
- Replace `%` with the access point.  The "%" gives permission to access from anywhere.  You can replace this with `localhost` or an IP address.

**From the Phpmyadmin:**

Phpmyadmin has a command interface for the database also.  You can click on the **SQL** link and type the same commands from the steps above there.

Comment: I login as root but the terminal says mysql can be found in the following packages:  mysql-client-core-5.7 mariadb-client-core-10.0.

Comment: You don't have to log into the computer as root.  Personally I would discourage it.  Exit out of root and run this command from normal user: `sudo apt install mysql-client`.  Then try the steps in the answer.